# VPython startMenu

Tags: menu, block, vpython

My main program for a Bloxorz-Type program is working fine. Only issue I have is having to implement a system where the game shows a message on the screen if the block falls off the map, and a gameFinished message on the screen when the block hits the hole vertically. I'm thinking the way it would work is to match the coordinates of the hole and if the coordinates of the hole match the square-bases of the block, it will show a message. 
My first real issue is being able to display a startMenu message, where it will display "Press S to Start" and "press Q to quit". I know how to use the scene.kb.getkey(), the only problem is displaying the text on the screen, which i will implement into my main while True loop. Here is my code:

```
from __future__ import division, print_function
from visual import *
import math, sys
from visual.graph import *
from sys import exit
"""Necessary Python Libraries"""


# top, left, bottom, right, front, back
tlbrfb = ( 2.0, -0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5, -0.5 )        #the area that the block covers (dimensions)
Top = 0
Left = 1
Bottom = 2
Right = 3
Front = 4
Back = 5


"""Modules defining the Movement of the Block"""
def moveRight():
    global tlbrfb
    for r in range(0, 9):
        rate(30)
        block.rotate( angle = pi/18, axis = vector( 0, 0, -1), origin = vector(tlbrfb[Right], 0, 0) ) #pi/18 = 10degrees, 
    tlbrfb = (tlbrfb[Right]-tlbrfb[Left], tlbrfb[Right], 0, tlbrfb[Right]+tlbrfb[Top], tlbrfb[Front], tlbrfb[Back]) #update block's state of stance

def moveDown():        
    global tlbrfb
    for r in range(0, 9):
        rate(30)
        block.rotate( angle = pi/18, axis = vector( +1, 0, 0), origin = vector(0, 0, tlbrfb[Front]) )
    tlbrfb = (tlbrfb[Front]-tlbrfb[Back], tlbrfb[Left], 0, tlbrfb[Right], tlbrfb[Front]+tlbrfb[Top], tlbrfb[Front])

def moveLeft():            
    global tlbrfb
    for r in range(0, 9):
        rate(30)
        block.rotate( angle = pi/18, axis = vector( 0, 0, +1), origin = vector(tlbrfb[Left], 0, 0) )
    tlbrfb = (tlbrfb[Right]-tlbrfb[Left], tlbrfb[Left]-tlbrfb[Top], 0, tlbrfb[Left], tlbrfb[Front], tlbrfb[Back] )

def moveUp():      
    global tlbrfb
    for r in range(0, 9):
        rate(30)
        block.rotate( angle = pi/18, axis = vector( -1, 0, 0), origin = vector(0, 0, tlbrfb[Back]) )
    tlbrfb = (tlbrfb[Front]-tlbrfb[Back], tlbrfb[Left], 0, tlbrfb[Right], tlbrfb[Back], tlbrfb[Back]-tlbrfb[Top])



level1 = [    #array on the tile placement
    [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0]
]

def draw_level(array):
    for y in range(0, len(array)):
        for x in range(0, len(array[y])): 
            if array[y][x] == 1:
                box( pos=vector(x, -0.1, y), length=0.9, width = 0.9, height = 0.2, color = vector(0.9, 0.8, 0.8))


block = box( pos=vector(0,1,0), length = 1, width = 1, height = 2, color = vector(0.9, 0.9, 0.5))

def handle_events():
    key = scene.kb.getkey()
    if key =="up":
        moveUp()
    elif key =="down":
        moveDown()
    elif key == "left":
        moveLeft()
    elif key == "right":
        moveRight()
    elif key == "q":
        quit()
    elif key == "escape":
        quit()

def mainGameLoop():
    while True:
        scene.center = vector(4.5, 0, 2)
        scene.forward = scene.center - vector(2, 6, 10)
        scene.background = vector(0.57, 0.2, 0.2)
        draw_level(level1) #draw mapout
        handle_events()

while True:
    mainGameLoop()
    handle_events()
    print(block.pos)
```

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: I need help in making a start Menu that displays "Press S to Start" which I will then use key input to link to the mainGameLoop.